# How to make horizontal orientation (album) word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word

How to make horizontal orientation (album) word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to adjust the Page Setup orientation (landspace vs portrait)?   If so you are looking for [TogglePortrait method of the PageSetup object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.pagesetup_members.aspx).